# I want to write only method names in notepad with using eclipse in java

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

I have a lot of methods in a `ClassA`. I want to learn how many methods and what are  methods' name?

I want to write code in same ClassA and this method's action is list of the method names in ClassA.

Comment: I dont get it. what do you want???

Comment: What is the use and advantage of this? and where it will helpful?

Comment: Take a look at `Reflection`. More specifically, `Class.getDeclaredMethods()`

Comment: Take a look at Pshemo answer.. Anyway, you should be more precise on your questions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection in this case [`java.lang.reflect.Method#getDeclaredMethods`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) seems useful.

```
Method[] methods = ClassA.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

You can iterate over all elements in `methods` and invoke its `getName` to get name of each method

```
List<String> methodNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (Method method : methods) {
    methodNames.add(method.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void listMyMethods() {

    final Class<? extends Object> c = this.getClass();

    for ( Method m : c.getDeclaredMethods() ) {
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `getMethods` will return only `public` methods including inherited ones.

Comment: Or, you could make a static version.  That might make more sense.

Comment: You're right Pshemo.  +1 for you.  I'll leave my answer, because `m.toString()` will probably give the OP more of the information he's looking for.